# Devise: How to create a new user being already logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm going to create a multi user app, so, I will have a admin user that will have permission to create new ones.

I've created the `UsersController`but when trying to create a new user, being already signed in, I'm getting redirect to root_path with an error message that says "You are already signed in".

So, what should I do to make this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found.

I have just to removed the `registerable` module from devise and it works.

Comment: Same stinkin' problem I had! Took me over an hour to figure it out (by finding this answer). Thanks!

Comment: @KleberS. Where is that specifically?  i.e. did you edit a certain file..?

Comment: Nevermind.  users.rb (model)  In case anyone else is wondering.

Comment: When I removed ":registerable", it made me unable to sign in at all (presumably because it's no longer 'registerable')…anyone else have this? (Using Rails 4, btw)

Comment: does that mean after we remove registerable module we need to create new controller, methods and views ourselves or we can use devise's existing controller, methods and views?

Comment: @TejasPatel yes :( If you need registrations, it is better to rename action of /users/create to /users/create_something, as you see in the second answer

Answer (score 8):

In a controller method can't you just go:

```
def create_user
    @user = User.new(:email => params[:email], :password => params[:password])
    @user.save
    ...
end
```

Comment: You mean, create a `form_tag` instead the `form_for`?

Comment: You can use whatever you want.

Comment: It is better to do this with a separate Admin model using `devise_for :admin`

Comment: Going this way, if I need to have a `manager`role, should I create another model to allow it to create new users too? it doesn't make much sense..

Comment: @KleberS. Sorry, I meant Admin controller and namespace.

Answer (score 3):

There is another solution.

You must override registration controller and remove action (or actions) from `prepend_before_filter`.

`DeviseRegistrationController` source is [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb).

You can see:

```
prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create, :cancel]
```

It jumps into `require_no_authentication` before create method. If you want create new user while you are logged in, just remove `:create` from array.

Comment: Worked for me :) Thanks for that.
One thing I'm wondering though, is if you have a solution for protecting "/users/sign_up" from being accessible to everyone

Comment: I had to modify the relevant line to `prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:cancel]`

maybe a newer version of devise.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I am doing it in 2015

```
# in your terminal
rails g controller Registrations
```

Registrations controller should look like this,

```
# registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [:new]

  def new
    super
  end

end
```

The important line is the `skip_before_filter...`
That will disable the requirement that there be no user logged in.

The routes for the controller looks like this,

```
# routes.rb
devise_for :users,
    controllers: {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

That will tell devise to use your custom registrations controller

Finally, setting up a custom route to that action:

```
# routes.rb
as :user do
  get "/register", to: "registrations#new", as: "register"
end
```

Comment: -1 Doesn't explain that `user` and `users` is the name of the model, instead of a reserved word. Also `Invalid route name, already in use`.

Comment: These methods are deprecate in rails 5.1 please check: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/637

Answer (score 3):

I added in the Registrations Controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    ...
    skip_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create]
    ...
end
```

And it worked for me. I can now go and create a new user.

Answer (score 2):

You could either override the default devise controller and add in your custom logic, or, It would probably be easier however to make a new (Admin) controller and simply create a user using one of it's actions.

```
@user = User.create!(:name => params[:foo], :email => params[:bar])
redirect_to @user
```

Devise has loads of guides on how to customise it's behaviour here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages

This one in particular may be of interest to you: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-Users-with-an-Admin-Role-(CanCan-method) But make sure to have a look over the rest of the articles, there's a lot of them.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have saw this before and that doesn't seem to have anything "special" at least on the `create` method.

Answer (score 1):

in case someone still looking for help, because it tooks a while for this to work , no clear answers

in your controller

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def add_user
    @user = User.new(user_params)
     if @user.save!
       redirect_to root_path
     end
  end

  private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
end
```

in your routes :

```
get  'employees',  to: 'users#new'
post 'employees',  to: 'users#add_user'
```

and finally a form like this:

```
<%= form_for User.new , :url => {:action => "add_user"} do |user| %>
  <%=user.email_field :email%>
  <%=user.password_field :password%>
  <%=user.password_field :password_confirmation%>

  <%=user.submit 'add'%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Answer (score 0):

@Mourkeer +1
For simple_form 4.2.0 take @Mourkeer code and replace `route.rb` by:

```
# route.rb
devise_for :users, path_names: { registration: "registrations" }
```