# How can an admin add another user or admin accounts in ruby devise without logging them in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have an admin account which logs into a separate account page. I want to have the ability to add a new account without logging them in I tried using this

```
<%= link_to "Add a New Account", new_user_registration_path %>
```

to redirect to the pre-existing sign up view but I keep running into the following message in the application.

```
You are already signed in.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140117/allow-a-user-to-add-new-users-in-devise-and-remain-logged-in-as-themselves

Comment: @PrakashMurthy Thanks but not the same issue I am having.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a different route to avoid the checking done by devise, such as adding "resources :users" to routes.rb and link_to( "Add a New Account", new_user_path ) in the views.

However, this will clash with the paths used by devise. Thus leading you to the the link @PrakashMurthy recommended his the comment.

Something like this should work: (of course, you'll need the users_controller code too.)

add this your routes.rb

```
resources :admin_users, controller: "users"
```

and change this in your views

```
<%= link_to "Add a New Account", new_admin_user_path %>
```