# Devise users create other users while logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In devise I'm trying to make it so that a Logged in user can create a new user via the Devise signup form.

Currently I've tried overriding the controller but it keeps redirecting me back to the root page due to me being logged in.

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create, :cancel]

  protected

  def create
    User.create!({:email => params[:email], :roles => [''], :password => params[:password], :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation] })
  end

  def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }, skip: [:sessions]
```

Am I missing something obvious, because I assumed the code below would allow it so I could view the form when I'm logged in?

```
  skip_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create, :cancel]
```

**Solution:**

I was being too specific in my signup route it was set as devise/registration#new instead of registrations#new

If anyone reading this in future gets stuck, let me know and i'll try my best to help! :)

Comment: you can visit the following link for your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140117/allow-a-user-to-add-new-users-in-devise-and-remain-logged-in-as-themselves

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow a user to add new users in Devise, and remain logged in as themselves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140117/allow-a-user-to-add-new-users-in-devise-and-remain-logged-in-as-themselves)

Comment: @Manish My routes are correct, which seemed to be the issue in that question.

Comment: @Iceman I read that post, it didn't seem to fix my issue as my routes were correct

Comment: Don't use RegistrationsController for this purpose. You better create your own action, for example `UsersController#create`. This will give you more control and avoid problems.