# Rails devise and authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my database website, I was able to implement where a user can sign up ONLY if a different user is logged in for security purposes. In other words, the sign up page is only visible to users that is logged in.

For example, let's say Bob wants to sign up for the website, but he cannot sign up. The only way for Bob to get an account is for Kevin to sign him up because he has an account and is able to sign Bob up.

Now I want a way where certain users can sign someone up. Let's make Kevin an admin and Stuart a non-admin. Only Kevin can sign a user up and even though Stuart can log in, he cannot sign Bob up because he is not an admin. In the database website, I want to hardcode Kevin's email to the code where only he can sign a user up. This is what I want to do. How can I do it? Where in the code do I do that?

Code where a new user is signed up

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
```

```
 <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% if !user_signed_in? %>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Home', vendors_path %>
</article>

<% end %>
```

Location of the link to sign up a user

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Deucex</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class = "auth">
      <% if !user_signed_in? %>
        <button class = "signed_in"><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></button>
    <% end %>

    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <div class = "buttons">
          <button class = "button"><%= link_to("Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %> </button>
          <button class="button">
        <%= link_to 'Create a new account', new_account_path %><br />
      </button>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    </div>
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

registrations controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new]

  def new
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: It sounds to me like basically Kevin will be an admin and Bob will be non admin,  I would say create these roles as a enum on the users table so admins can view the sing up page and non admins cannot.

Comment: an enum? never heard of that